# Make a ball bounce when pressed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game where you can click a ball using `SpriteKit`. At the moment, I can click anywhere on the screen and the ball moves up.

I want it to only move or bounce when I click the ball. What am I doing wrong?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit


class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKSpriteNode()
    var grass = SKSpriteNode()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        ball = (self.childNode(withName: "ball") as? SKSpriteNode)!

        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 1
        self.physicsBody = border
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
        jump()
    }
    func touchUp(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
        ball.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "football-161132_640")
    }


    func jump() {
        ball.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "football-161132_640")
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: Int.random(in: -5...5), dy: 80))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple touches:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if ball.contains(location) {
            jump()
        }
    }
}
```

Single touch:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if ball.contains(location) {
            jump()
        }
    }
}
```